# change c to cpp file in ccs v6

Tags: c++, c, include

While using ccs v6, I tried to change the c file to cpp file. The original c file contains several header files.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "types.h"
#include "evmomapl138.h"
#include "evmomapl138_timer.h"
#include "evmomapl138_i2c.h"
#include "test_led_dip.h"
```

But after changing it into cpp file, it returns an error of expected an identifier in types.h

```
#ifndef TYPES_H
#define TYPES_H

typedef unsigned char   uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short  uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int    uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long   ulong_t;
typedef signed char     int8_t;
typedef signed short    int16_t;
typedef signed int      int32_t;
typedef signed long     long_t;

typedef enum 
{
    false = 0,
    true = 1
}bool_e;

#endif
```

The compiler said false =0 and true = 1 sentences expected an identifier. But I have modified the header file inclusion to become

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "types.h"
}
```

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If you're going to try to compile a file written for one language with a differing language compiler (and C and C++ **are** different, not just sub/super-set), prepare to expect things like unintentional use of reserved words in the latter being used by the former. Such is the risks of switching languages. This break is compile-time blatant. I can assure you there are plenty possible bugs that will not exhibit until *run-time*. Best of luck in finding those.

Comment: Maybe you should have `typedef bool bool_e;` when the file is compiled for C++: `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `typedef bool bool_e;` / `#else` / `...existing code...` / `#endif`.

Comment: The C++ header files are `<cstdio>` and `<ctypes>`.

Answer (score 1):

In cpp true and false are keywords.

Comment: Then how to fix it? How to define a bool in c and call it in cpp?

Comment: There are lots of ways.  You might fix one problem and then find another.  Try using what Galik said <cstdio> and <ctypes>.